# unable to Invoke CreateAPIKeyRequest from Lambda function and resulting in permission errors

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am invoking the CreateAPIKeyRequest POST call from Lambda Function with intention to respond with generated API key ID for each invocation. Got error message that Lambda function does not have permissions to invoke createAPI POST call.

Code for the same is below:

```
 AmazonApiGateway client = AmazonApiGatewayClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("us-east-1").build();
 CreateApiKeyRequest keyReq = new CreateApiKeyRequest();
 keyReq.setName("KEY_NAME");
 keyReq.setDescription("KEY_DESC");
 keyReq.setEnabled(true);
  
 CreateApiKeyResult keyRes = client.createApiKey(keyReq);
```

After reading the documentation came across that i need to provide permissions so assigned Resource based permissions to Lambda function with ARN : arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/apikeys.

Getting the error message as "**User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/createAPIKey-role-s4puynzg/createAPIKey is not authorized to perform: apigateway:POST on resource: arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/apikeys because no identity-based policy allows the apigateway:POST action (Service: AmazonApiGateway;**"

any inputs?

Comment: did you redeploy the application for policy changes to propagate?

Comment: yes, i redeployed. but not working

Comment: Please share the policy and permission you have assigned.

Comment: I have attached the policy from the list "AmazonAPIGatewayAdministrator" to lambda function then it is working. Is it only way or is there a way to add the the same permissions from Lambda by going thru add permissions?